# understand the following android code about constructor

Tags: java

```
public Gameplay instantiateGameplay(Class<? extends Gameplay> clazz) {
    try {
        Constructor<? extends Gameplay> constructor;


        constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { Game.class } );
        return constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { this });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Instantiate gameplay '" + clazz.getSimpleName() + "' failed.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

normally, when we instantiated a new class, the constructor is inside the class file.  what's this clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] { Game.class } ) thing? It looks kind of odd. whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

It is java reflection at work.

Answer (score 1):

This is using the java reflection API to get information about classes/objects available only at runtime. In particular, the method takes an argument declared to be a generic type of any object that extends from GamePlay. Since one of many classes could be passed in, at runtime, the code

```
constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { Game.class } );
        return constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { this });
```

grabs hold of the constructor for the actual argument passed in and creates a new instance of the object with it.